# Is there any way to compile ink contract to EVM bytecode?

Tags: ink, smart-contract, evm, ethereum

I just wonder if there is any way to deploy my ink! contract to ethereum network. As far as I know, ink! contract compiles to WASM bytecode, not EVM, so it's not possible, right? Or maybe there are some WASM-EVM converter-tools..?

Comment: The only thing that I'm aware of is actually a Solidity to ink! transpiler which is currently under development: https://github.com/Supercolony-net/sol2ink. The Solang compiler already allows you to compile Solidity code to WASM. But AFAIK there is nothing in the other direction, neither Solidity->ink!, nor WASM->EVM.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not possible to compile ink smart contract to evm bytecode. As per [ink doc here](https://ink.substrate.io/ink-vs-solidity), ink contract can compile in **ANY WASM VM** and If anyhow if we try to compile then, I think we may face some issue, which are point out in [this article](https://www.parity.io/blog/wasm-smart-contract-development/).